# Can I set the ErrorCheckingObjects in Excel per worksheet?

Tags: excel, com, automation, ole

I am generating a CSV file which I then open in Excel via OLE Automation. Because of the format of the data, Excel shows many "Inconsistent Formula" warnings (a green icon in corner of each cell).  I can turn this off application-wide via automation, using:

```
objExcel.ErrorCheckingOptions.InconsistentFormula = false
```

But doing so updates the user preferences permanently and the user needs to know to re-enable that option, if needed.

Is there any way to turn off error checking for an entire Worksheet or Workbook, without affecting the current user's global settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that's possible, no. The only thing I can suggest is keeping the Excel application object alive until the user is done with it and then switching the `InconsistentFormula` property back to true before exiting the application.